# C# abstract generic class create derived instance

Tags: c#, generics, abstract

I've one abstract class and n other dervided

```
public abstract class CConfig<T_RESP> where T_RESP : CLinkResp
{
    public abstract Boolean Exec(out T_RESP oResp);
}

public class CConfigUnrecognized : CConfig<CLinkRespNone>
{
    public override Boolean Exec(out CLinkResp oResp)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class CConfig...
```

I'd like to create an abstract oConfig

```
CConfig<CLinkRespNone> oConfig;
```

And after, decide to create the appropriate oConfig
Exemple :

```
oConfig = new CConfigUnrecognized(oLstCmdLine);
```

and after call this associated Exec(...) function.

But, in this case I've got this error :
CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type CConfigUnrecognized to CConfig

Can I use abstract class and generic type to call only one executor ?

Thanks in advance
Eric.

Comment: doing something like `CConfig<CLinkRespNone> oConfig = new CConfigUnrecognized();` should work.  Can you show a complete example that reproduces your problem exactly?

Comment: This shouldn't compile, because `CConfigUnrecognized.Exec` should take a `CLinkRespNone` in order to override `CConfig.Exec`. And if I fix that, then `CConfig<CLinkRespNone> oConfig = new CConfigUrecognized(...)` definitely compiles. Your code as posted isn't demonstrating the exact problem you're having. Consider the possibility that you're not dealing with the `CConfig` that you think you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

**Juharr :
I cannot write
`CConfig<CLinkRespNone> oConfig = new CConfigUnrecognize` beacause oConfig Already exist

**Jeroen Mostert :
I have a lot of switch case that create the specific new cConfig : 

// Create corresponding object and execute it function
`switch (iType)
{
 // Kills
 case K_APP_KILL_STD:
  oConfig = new CConfigKillStd(oLstCmdLine);
  break;
 case K_APP_KILL_SMART:
  oConfig = new CConfigKillSmart(oLstCmdLine);
  break;
 case K_APP_KILL:
  ...
}`
// And i want to execute one Exec
`oConfig.Exec();`

Thanks...